# Can't get my free account to work... tried 2 emails same thing

Tags: azure

I'm new to Azure, I have not used the product, just trying to learn how things work, so I decided to take the training at MS, so now they say I need to create a free azure account, I tried to create it but I get the message:

[image]

Not sure what they mean by this, they can't say I had azure before as I don't even know how that works, just learning now... I just need it to learn how it works... here's an screenshot of my current training...
[image]
[image]
any help on this will make my day! I need to practice and I'm afraid of entering my CC as I had a bad experience with Amazon Web Services billing me, thank you.

Comment: Similar question has been answered in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/608114/unable-to-create-the-azure-free-account.html). You can check for reference.

Comment: @Jahnavi this does not fix the problem :-(

Comment: Still showing the same error?

Comment: yes... same thing...

Comment: Did any other azure accounts enable with you previously?